# Apply options to all dropdowns in $scope using Angular-Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

In Angular-Bootstrap is it possible to apply options to all dropdown elements in the scope?

I see from the [Angular-Bootstrap dropdown documentaiton](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/dropdowns) it is possible to apply options using granular data attributes for each dropdown instance, or globally in the entire app using the `$dropdownProvider` in the app config.

But I see no way to apply options to the entire scope without making them global.